# Ruby on rails array - no implicit conversion of symbol into integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I made a table component using react js, which uses columns to display data (which works fine with other data). For example, column 1 would show the title, column 2 the year, and column 3 the format.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```
{"movies": [{"title": "Iron Man", "year": "2008", "format": "DVD"}, {"title": "Iron Man 2", "year": "2010", "format": "DVD"}, {"title": "Iron Man 3", "year": "2013", "format": "DVD"}]}
```

Here is my code to populate the table, but it does not seem to work:

```
@movieList = #Makes a call to my mock API to get list of movies
@movies = Array.new

@movieList.each do |item|
 @movie = Hash.new
 @movie[:column1] = item[:title]
 @movie[:column2] = item[:year]
 @movie[:column3] = item[:format]
 @movies << @movie
end
```

I need some advice to overcome a "no implicit conversion of symbol into integer error" I get. Could anyone offer some advice and point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

use `@movieList["movies"].each`

**explanation**

The issue here, is that you act as though your `@movieList` is ann *array*, when it is actually a *hash* (assuming `@movieList` is the JSON you showed).

`each` works on both arrays and hashes. However, when you use it on a hash, the block is passed `|key, val|`. Also, assigning block variables is optional. So, when you say `@movieList.each do |item|`, `item` is actually the *top level key* of the hash ("movies").

Strings such as "movies" respond to `[]` indexing with *numbers*. That's why you get the error `no implicit conversion of symbol into integer` ... because you pass a symbol to `String#[]` and it expects an integer.

Another way to write this code, that is more idiomatic, would be like so:

```
@movies = @movieList["movies"].map do |movie|
  {
    column1: movie["title"],
    column2: movie["year"],
    column3: movie["format"]
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try reassigning

`@movieList = @movieList[:movies]` this will solve your problem. You're trying to iterate a object instead of an array.

lemme know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop movies using `@movieList["movies"]` as your JSON is a hash that has a key 'movies' and an array of movies as a value => `{'movies': [{...},{...},...]}`

As @max pleaner explained assigning block variables is optional, but when you use `each` on a hash(your JSON in this case) and provide only one block variable (instead of two refering to the keys and values of the hash), your key-value pairs are converted to two-element arrays inside the block where first element is the key and second one is the value of the pair.

Your `item` looks like this inside your each block -
`['movies', [{movie1}, {movie2},..]]`, hence:

```
item[0] # 'movies'
item[1] # [{movie1}, {movie2},...]
```

As arrays expect indexing with integers and you supply symbol (`item[:title]`), you receive:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```